# Has anyone tried adapting "Rivers of London" as a RPG setting?

Tags: campaign-settings, fantasy, historical-settings, modern

I am a big fan of the series of books and graphic novels by Ben Aaronovitch, collectively named after the first book in series, [Rivers of London](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rivers_of_London_(book_series)) (sometimes also called the Peter Grant series after the main protagonist). For those not familiar, here is a brief extract from the main novel's description on Wikipedia:

> The novel centres around the adventures of Peter Grant, a young officer in the Metropolitan Police; who, following an unexpected encounter with a ghost, is recruited into the small branch of the Met that deals with magic and the supernatural.

Not unlike the Dresden Files (although quite different in the tone), the series is set in present day, but it reveals that magic, fantastical creatures, parallel universes etc are in fact real. I have been playing with the idea of adapting this series into a RPG setting, but wanted to first check if anyone has tried that before, so we can compare notes.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. Sadly, the site can't handle questions calling for conversations. [This question should be posed on one of the forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/8610) or taken to *RPG.SE*'s [chat]. However, once you establish a system and have some questions about how that setting works or the rules being used o explore it, those questions can totally be asked here. Thank you for participating and have fun!